# angular how to disable validation on condition ng-required

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs, input

I have a variable on the scope which I use to check for condition

```
$scope.data = $resource().query(); //returns array always
```

So i have a regular validation with a ng-required directive

```
<input ng-required="{{data.length}}"/>
```

now when the data is initially loaded into a 2 length array the ng-required validates the field and everything works, 
but if I were to set ng-required to [], ng-required will still validate as a regular required,

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.data = []
});
```

how do I disable validation on ng-validation = "false" again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ng-required` accepts an expression, no need to wrap in `{{` `}}`

```
<input ng-required="data.length"/>
```

Basic Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/Uxe5Q/ (inspect to see the validation being added and removed.)